# Creating SVG from Visio Drawing - with user defined attributes & shape formats

Tags: c#, java, svg, visio

I am trying to export VSD file to JPEG. We cannot use Visio for conversion (MS Visio not supported in server & is not suggested by Microsoft too).

So initially we tried to manually export VSD to SVG from users machine using Visio itself & upload it to server & process the file. SVG manipulation & conversion to JPG/PDF is working great.

But only problem is with SVG creation part. SVG output by Visio is breaking all shape formats & adding extra spaces, but gives user defined attributes & info. I have tried Libre Office's Draw this also breaks all format & skips user defined attributes too.

Is there any way to export visio drawing (VSD/VDX) - which can preserve user defined attr & text information and formats to SVG.

Please let me know if there is any open source converted available in Java/C#, which we shall make use of it!

Comment: please try tool [HTML Export](http://unmanagedvisio.com/products/svg-publish/) aka SVG publish by user [Nikolay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929187/nikolay)